# How to insert an image and not get error message when resizing

Tags: errors, compilation-error

Hi I am trying to insert an image in a document and have the width of the image be the same as the width of the text.

I have included the following and cannot seem to get the display command to work.

```latex
\usepackage{graphics}
```

I am trying to display image using

```latex
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my-image}
```

I receive the following error message:

```latex
width=\textwidth ]{my-image} 
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need the `graphicx` package (`\usepackage{graphicx}`) instead.

Comment: I used the correct package and received the following error message "LaTeX Error: File 'graphicsx.sty' not found". @PhelypeOleinik thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have a typo. You did `\usepackage{graphicsx}`, but it's `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: AHHH!!! It worked! Thank you so much @PhelypeOleinik!!

Comment: You're welcome :-)